# Holding tournament, how to store all player scores

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine, storage

I'm looking to add a tournament to my app, where:

- Tournament runs for 24 hours
- Players can keep playing and store just their highest score
- When the tournament ends, I want to tell the player where they ranked out of all players that entered.

Players will be competing in a simple game with themselves on their mobile device, but the leaderboard will be global (worldwide).

Where can I store the players scores during the tournament and access them once it's over?

Comment: Is this an online service for a multiplayer game, or a local thing? It's not clear exactly what you intend to make here.

Comment: Players will just be competing in a simple game with themselves on their mobile device, but it will use a global leaderboard

Comment: and by "global leaderboard" you mean an online one, or "global" in your case means the same leaderboard for all the players on that mobile device? :)

Comment: A worldwide leaderboard. Say players play a flappy bird style game on their mobile (within my app), their score goes to the leaderboard, and once the tournament is over, it tells the player their worldwide rank and shows the scores.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to go about this, and the 24h reset might make things a bit complicated:

**1.** Probably the easiest one is to use the platform specific gaming features through Unity's social API. Some docs on this here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/net-SocialAPI.html
This allows you to use e.g. GameCenter on iOS or Google Play Games

- [+] easy to implement
- [+] free
- [-] you might not be able to access every platform specific feature
- [-] normally not cross-platform

**2.** Implement the platform specific gaming features yourself natively. With this solution you can definitely access all platform specific features.

- [+] free
- [-] normally not cross-platform

**3.** Use some 3rd party cross-platform leaderboard service, I'm sure a simple search will yield a few of these, most probably have Unity plugins as well.

- [+] should be easy to implement
- [-] probably not free
- [-] features might be limited

**4.** Make your own. You can write a simple web API that connects to some database and deploy it to a cloud provider. This is complicated as you suddenly have another thing to develop, secure and maintain... plus pay for the hosting. But as it's your design it can do anything you want - for example your 24h tournament feature might be one of these things.

- [+] can do anything
- [-] not free to host
- [-] you have to write/maintain your own

---

I think you could get away with for example creating a separately named leaderboard for every day as a way around resetting the leaderboard every day, but you'll have to look into the specific capabilities of all the platforms.

Comment: 1 and 2 are out due to not all players will want to signin to game center/google play services.

3. Honestly couldn't find a solid service that was available. Playfab was an option, except they limit the leaderboard to returning 100 entries. 

4. Seems excessive for this type of thing.

Maybe i'm wrong, but that's my thoughts

Comment: In my opinion, you'll have to go for option 4. It's not excessive since you want specific behaviour at global level. By not using services, you don't get the **free data hosting** they provide. Also, these services provides daily leaderboards which reset every day at the same hour. But they are (correct me if i'm wrong) always used along with weeks and longer leaderboards.

Comment: Your requirements don't make this easy. Maybe take a look at non-gaming-specific online services, such as Firebase or Realm.